# How determine Hive database size?

Tags: bash, hive, hiveql

How determine Hive's database size from `Bash` or from `Hive CLI`?

`hdfs` and `hadoop` commands are also avaliable in `Bash`.

Answer (score 2):

A database in hive is a metadata storage - meaning it holds information about tables and has a default location. Tables in a database can also be stored anywhere in `hdfs` if `location` is specified when creating a table.

You can see all tables in a database using `show tables` command in `Hive CLI`.

Then, for each table, you can find its location in `hdfs` using `describe formatted <table name>` (again in `Hive CLI`).

Last, for each table you can find its size using `hdfs dfs -du -s -h /table/location/`

I don't think there's a single command to measure the sum of sizes of all tables of a database. However, it should be fairly easy to write a script that automates the above steps. Hive can also be invoked from `bash CLI` using: `hive -e '<hive command>'`

Comment: Alex, thanks for answer. But I need to measure a whole database that can contain tens of tables.

Comment: @AleksYa I updated the answer: I don't think there's a single command to measure the sum of sizes of all tables of a database. However, it should be fairly easy to write a script

Answer (score 1):

Show Hive databases on HDFS

```
sudo hadoop fs -ls /apps/hive/warehouse
```

Show Hive database size

```
sudo hadoop fs -du -s -h  /apps/hive/warehouse/{db_name}
```

Comment: Won't work with tables that have explicit `LOCATION` elsewhere. Especially EXTERNAL tables. Plus, tables for `default` database are stores in the root dir, not in a subdirectory. And the subdirs are `{db_name}.db` by the way...

Answer (score 1):

if you want the size of your complete database run this on your "warehouse"

```
hdfs dfs -du -h /apps/hive/warehouse
```

this gives you the size of each DB in your warehouse

if you want the size of tables in a specific DB run:

```
hdfs dfs -du -h /apps/hive/warehouse/<db_name>
```

run a "grep warehouse" on hive-site.xml to find your warehouse path